# Laravel 5.6: Ejecutar comando cada minuto

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, apache, xampp

Cree un comando para enviar un correo, probe el comando ejecutandolo en la consola y funciona perfectamente. Sin embargo quiero que se haga de manera automatica sin tener que ingresar el comando en la consola. Lo añadi al kernel para que se ejecute cada minuto:

```
<?php

namespace efsystem\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands = [
    Commands\SendEmailEfsystem::class,
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('emails:send')->everyMinute();
}

/**
 * Register the commands for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function commands()
{
    $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
}
```

Solo que no se como hacer para inicar el proceso para que comience a ejecutarse el comando cada minuto. Estoy usando Xammp.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que setear un Cron, te dejo un ejemplo:

http://www.rephp.com/configurando-un-cronjob-en-windows-xampp.html

Comment: Por favor añade lo relevante del enlace aquí pues respuestas con solo links se consideran de baja calidad